# Hangout API Deprecation

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am planing to do an app integrated with Google Hangouts but I need to know who are in the hangout group I could have done that with Google+ Hangouts API but it has depracated. What is your suggestion to find out Who are in the hangout group like a list of people in the group. How can I do that any idea ? (JS or PHP are prefered languages to do that) thanks

For example in this site he handles this problem how I dont know 
http://www.free4talk.com

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Yeah sorry for not being clear I was trying to explain my problem like I am searching for a way like using CURL or other libraries to access hangout group people list but cant find @DaImTo

Comment: Just saying that you want to use cURL doesn't mean anything. It's just a tool, not some magic that you plug in and everything "just works".  And there's nothing mutually-exclusive between using cURL and a public, well-documented API. They're used together quite often.

Comment: Yeah lets say I tried to logged in google and open the groups link and get people list from it but couldnt logged in and get the list. But I thought you understood what I ment by cURL if you didnt sorry @Patrick Q

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Not only is the Hangout Video API deprecated... it has been discontinued for external applications.

There is no public API that gives you access to any information about a Hangout Video, nor a Hangout Text Chat.

**Update** - Since you insist this is what you want to do, let me add this.

Don't.

Really... don't.

Trying to work around a platform that is actively trying to not let you do anything is a good indication that your time is better spent finding a better platform. It is pretty easy to find a better, more open, platform that will integrate with what you're trying to do. (Whatever that is, since you haven't described that. And you haven't described what you've tried, which is why the question is at risk of being closed.)

Hangouts isn't it.

Comment: I dont mean any api , A way to do that like CURL or any other things to join to group and take people list but I need to login google first and they made it hard to logged in by CURL. @Prisoner And I saw someone did that he is using hangout integrated with his app but I dont know what he is using

Comment: Now I described way I tried but couldnt fake google with cookies for something elso get logged in to open hangout group and as ı said someone does but I dont know how he gets people list from it @Prisoner